# How to import a python module where filename contains '-' character

Tags: python, import, module

Is it possible to import a module that contains '-' characters in the filename?

i.e.

```
import my-python-module
```

or do you have to rename the file, i.e.

```
mv my-python-module.py my_python_module.py
```

and then..

```
import my_python_module
```

Comment: You can't and really should not bother dealing with something like that. The module should conform to Python's rules.

Comment: I assume not spotting a duplicate question is a down-votable offence? As opposed to the question being poor (the other identical question has a score of 52). I guess duplicate questions do waste some peoples time so probably fair enough?

Comment: turns out it isn't - http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10841/how-should-duplicate-questions-be-handled

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [PEP 8 -- Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#package-and-module-names):

> Modules should have short, all-lowercase names. Underscores can be used in the module name if it improves readability. Python packages should also have short, all-lowercase names, although the use of underscores is discouraged.

PEP 8 is the more-or-less "official" coding standard for Python code.

Comment: ahh - i see. I think the developer came from a lisp/emacs background so using '-' in the filenames would have seemed quite normal.. won't be a problem to rename

Comment: It might be worth mentioning (especially to new python programmers) what PEP 8 is: the 'official' code standard guidelines. If everyone sort-of-keeps to them, then code will be a lot more reusable and easily read/written/debugged by other Python programmers. (I was just looking up the link when you answered:P)